# R3Route URL Router in C

Tags: c, url-routing

I trying to use the R3Route URL router in C and on the github page at https://github.com/c9s/r3 I see the following:

```
#include <r3/r3.h>

// create a router tree with 10 children capacity (this capacity can grow dynamically)
R3Node *n = r3_tree_create(10);

int route_data = 3;

// insert the R3Route path into the router tree
r3_tree_insert_path(n, "/bar", &route_data); // ignore the length of path
```

Could somebody please tell me what is route_data here? And why is it 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the source code of this lib and i found this :

```
#define r3_tree_insert_path(n,p,d) r3_tree_insert_pathl_ex(n,p,strlen(p), NULL, d, NULL)
```

where d is your int = 3

This is the new prototype of this func

```
R3Node * r3_tree_insert_pathl_ex(R3Node *tree, const char *path, int path_len, R3Route * route, void * data, char **errstr)
```

and in this func, data is just used at this line

```
if (route) {
        route->data = data;
}
```

route is a struct where definition could be find in r3.h

i search for this int everywhere in the code without success..

If you use this struct (R3Route), it could be usefull by passing an argument in your structure as void *, but you should try changing your int * by a NULL and try to execute your prog. I'm not really usefull because i don't know this library but this is everything i found. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! With NULL it works just fine but I'm not able to see the use of void *data here. Even if I pass in an int, I still can't figure out how I can get its value back when I match the route with a url.

Comment: It's defined in R3Route as (R3Route *)x->data if you want to use it, but I really don't know if it's usefull to use this var :)